# python word count(defaultdict) column not showing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, defaultdict

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
word_name = []
y = 0

text_list = ['france', 'spain', 'spain beaches', 'france beaches', 'spain best beaches']

word_freq = defaultdict(int)

for text in text_list:
    for word in text.split():
        word_freq[word] += 1
        word_name.append(word)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(word_freq, orient='index') \
.sort_values(0, ascending=False) \
.rename(columns={0: 'Word_freq'}) \
.rename(columns={0: 'Word'})
```

so I tried multiple ways to convert this into dataframe but it does not show the column name for the words. How am i able to indicate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know of the Counter class from the collections library? you can simply your code quite a bit by using that in-place of default dict.

```
from collections import Counter


text_list = ['france', 'spain', 'spain beaches', 'france beaches', 'spain best beaches']

counter_dict = Counter([split_word for word in text_list for split_word in word.split()]
#Counter({'france': 2, 'spain': 3, 'beaches': 3, 'best': 1})
```

then construct your dataframe with the `to_dict` appendage.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counter_dict
    ,
    orient="index",
    columns=["WordFreq"],
).rename_axis('Word')

         WordFreq
Word             
france          2
spain           3
beaches         3
best            1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, same thing here. I tested this and the column name 'Word' is missing in the CSV file #temp saving df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\example.csv', index = False, header=True)

Comment: @anon that's because your removing the index, change remove the `index=False` in your argument

Comment: oh god, thank you so much! it finally works. Trust me, I tried to even split it, transpose and convert it.

Comment: i tried to upvote but it did not allow me to do so, i am new here. i do my best not to seek help but o was stuck on this for too long.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "it does not show the column name for the words," but assuming that you want to set the column/index names properly, you can do this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(word_freq, orient='index')
>>> df = df.rename(columns={0: 'WordFreq'})
>>> df.index.name = 'Word'
>>> df
         WordFreq
Word
france          2
spain           3
beaches         3
best            1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so that indicated the column name but when I tried to save to CSV file, the column 'Word' is missing...                                                                                                          ```#temp saving
df.to_csv (r'C:\Users\example.csv', index = False, header=True)```